# How to unit test an if else statement

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I have the following method. How can I write a unit test for this function to make sure the machine is added to the repairs list?

```
public void AddMachineToRepairsList()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Would you like to add this Machine to the repairs list?");

    var addToRepairs = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();
    if (addToRepairs == "yes")
    {
        int cost = 0;
        int hoursWorked = 0;

        var machine = new Repair(cost, hoursWorked);
        Repairs.Add(machine);
        Console.WriteLine("Machine successfully added!");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter machine information again");
        this.Run();
    }     
}
```

Comment: You had a missing `"` on the first line, which I fixed for you.

Comment: 1) Which unit testing framework are you using?  2)  Usually unit testing is done on a non-void method to determine what the function is returning / erroring.  What exactly are you looking for here?

Comment: You can abstract the body of the function (everything after Console.ReadLine().ToLower()) into a separate, testable method - and then test that (you're probably not interested in whether the Console takes input/produces output correctly).

Comment: Being that this method mixes concerns (UI output, user input and business logic), it's not really of good design for unit testing. Separate those concerns and then the business logic can be unit tested.

Comment: You'd check the content of Repairs after the test has executed, having the Console stuff in here will make this horrible to test though, have the Read/WriteLine stuff outside of the method, so this has one responsibility.

Comment: @JNYRanger, I am using .NET Framework 4.5

Comment: All I want to test is whether the machine gets added or not. Which is functional so far but I need code coverage for it. So my Assert would look something like... Assert.AreEqual(1, repairUI.RepairList.Count);

Answer (score 0):

You will need to pass addToRepairs  as parameter to the method and call like

```
    Console.WriteLine("Would you like to add this Machine to the repairs list?");
    var addToRepairs = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();
    while(AddMachineToRepairsList(addToRepairs)==false) 
{
 Console.WriteLine("Please enter machine information again");
    this.Run();
}
```

Definition would be

```
public bool AddMachineToRepairsList(string option)
{
    string addToRepairs = "";
    if (addToRepairs == "yes")
    {
        int cost = 0;
        int hoursWorked = 0;

        var machine = new Repair(cost, hoursWorked);
        Repairs.Add(machine);
        Console.WriteLine("Machine successfully added!");
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }

}
```

Now one unit tests will be with value "yes" and one with "no" . you
can write unit test and assert the return value is true/false based on option passed

Comment: The execution won't even reach the AddMachineToRepairsList(string option) method. It just jumps to this.Run();